# ascending order check recursively

Tags: algorithm, recursion, math, divide-and-conquer, off-by-one

What I try to do is to check a given array is ordered in an ascending manner by divide-and-conquer approach.

I wonder what the logic behind the additional return case (`a⌊n/2⌋−1 ≤ a⌊n/2⌋`) is to reach to the final result. I attempted to solve the problem without looking at its solution but I couldn't figure out how the author discovers/devises `a⌊n/2⌋−1 ≤ a⌊n/2⌋` case. It is really hard for me to unearth the case.

Actually, **Why not `a⌊n/2⌋ ≤ a⌊n/2⌋+1` instead?** And the base case case, why I'm stackoverflowed when I remove equality from the base case, that is `h<l`?

[image]

with trial and error approach, I tried to write the following.

```
def co(a, l, h):
  if h <= l:
    return True
  mid = l + ((h-l)//2)
  cl = co(a, l, mid-1)
  rl = co(a, mid+1, h)
  return rl and cl and a[mid] < a[mid+1] 

    # how  is a[mid] < a[mid+1] devised ??
    # why not a[mid-1] < a[mid] ??

  

#c = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11,12]
c = [3, 5]


print(co(c, 0, len(c) - 1))
```

Comment: `n` is the length of the array (or the size of the current problem). For the smallest relevant case `n = 2`, the index `n//2 + 1` will be out of bounds, but `n//2 - 1`  won't.

Comment: You write: *"I tried to write the following"*, but then in that code you write *"how is a[mid] < a[mid+1] devised??"*.... So, did you write the code and then ask us about what you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

> And the base case case, why I'm stackoverflowed when I remove equality
> from the base case, that is h<l?

Assume `c=[3, 5]`. If you replace `h<=l` with `h<l`, then when you compute `co(a, 1, 1)`, then `mid = 1+0` ... then `rl = co (a, 1+1, 1)` and `a[2]` gives you stackoverflow.

> How  is `a[mid] <= a[mid+1]` devised ??

- **You need to compare the most-right element of subproblem1 with the most-left element of subproblem2. The order of these two elements are not taken into account in subproblem1 and subproblem2**.
- Be careful with Python indexing. 1) When you split the list into `a[l:mid-1]` and `a[mid+1,h]`, you leave out `a[mid-1]` and `a[mid]`. 2) When you write `co(c, 0, len(c) - 1)` you leave out the last element of `c` (see Comment4).

There are some mistakes in your code, see my comments.

```
def co(a, l, h):
  if h <= l:
    return True
  mid = l + ((h-l)//2)
  cl = co(a, l, mid-1)
  rl = co(a, mid+1, h)
  return rl and cl and a[mid] < a[mid+1] ### Comment1: this misses checking a[mid-1] <= a[mid]

    # how  is a[mid] < a[mid+1] devised ??  ### Comment2: you should use <= rather than <
    # why not a[mid-1] < a[mid] ??
 

#c = [12, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11,12]  ### Comment3: your code returns True for this unordered list!
#c = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11,12]
c = [3, 5]


print(co(c, 0, len(c) - 1))  ### Comment4: len(c)-1 should be len(c) otherwise it's not the whole list
```

Below, I fixed the list indexing in your code. Note that the test becomes `h <= l+1` because in Python the list `a[mid:mid+1]` contains one element.

```py
def co(a, l, h):
  if h <= l+1:
    return True
  mid = l + ((h-l)//2)
  cl = co(a, l, mid)
  rl = co(a, mid, h)
  return rl and cl and a[mid-1] <= a[mid]
```